# Deleting objects through foreign key relationship with T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Looking for a way to write the following LinQ to entities query as a T-SQL statement.

```
repository.ProductShells.Where(x => x.ShellMembers.Any(sm => sm.ProductID == pid)).ToList().ForEach(x => repository.ProductShells.Remove(x));
```

The below is obviously not correct but I need it to delete respective ProductShell object where
any ShellMember contains a ProductID equal to the passed in variable `pid`. I would presume this would involve a join statement to get the relevant ShellMembers.

```
repository.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("FROM Shellmembers WHERE ProductID={0} DELETE FK_ProductShell", pid);
```

I have cascade delete enabled for the FK_ShellMembers_ProductShells foreign key, so when I delete the ProductShell it will delete all the ShellMembers that are associated with it. I am going to pass this statement to System.Data.Entity `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always show table structures and foreign key linkages.
However, it should look something like this.

This assumes the link between the two tables is productshell.shellid=shellmembers.shellid

```
delete productshell
where shellid in (
    select shellid
    from shellmembers
    where productid={0}
    )
```

It can also be written as a join

```
delete productshell
from productshell
join shellmembers on productshell.shellid=shellmembers.shellid
where shellmembers.productid={0}
```